# How to locally deploy a Java webapp using docker & IntelliJ as the text editor?

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, web-applications, devops

Im totally new to docker and intelliJ, Im trying to deploy a Java webapp locally on my laptop. could you provide step-by-step instructions on how to do that?

Comment: How To Deploy a Webapp with Docker: https://medium.com/@mikenoethiger/how-to-deploy-a-webapp-with-docker-5149204e35f2

Comment: Have you read article recommended by @GilbertLeBlanc ? Did this article solve your problem ?